# adfs with subdomain not working

Tags: asp.net, subdomain, wif, global-asax, adfs2.0

I have a requirement for authentication with sts. I have done with poc where it is getting authenticated and coming back to realm. But our application is multi-tenant application having different sub domain for different tenants. like `client1.mediahub.org`, `client2.mediahub.org` while redirecting back after authentication losing Sub-Domain Information.

Tried Implement code

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += OnServiceConfigurationCreated;
}
Protected void OnServiceConfigurationCreated(object sender, ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RedirectingToIdentityProvider        += WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider;
}
protected void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider(object sender, RedirectingToIdentityProviderEventArgs e)
{
      // this method parses the HTTP_HOST and gets the first subdomain
       string realm = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

        e.SignInRequestMessage.Realm = realm;

}
```

but while redirecting back after it is giving exception at adfs after authentication.

I would like some help or link to references on implementing wif with subdomain.

Comment: It worked when i used wildcard ssl certificate with makecert

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i used wildcard ssl certificate with makecert